# Cannot create Win32 Console Application in VS 2013, Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Iam unable to create a new win32 console Application in VS 2013.
To create the console application I went to New Project-->chose win32 console application under visual c++-->changed the name of project and clicked OK.
But nothing happens and New Project dialog blinked and came back again.
I clicked OK again and again and It keeps coming back...
I googled and found nothing helpful.
I checked the logs and found nothing related to this.

Initially I was unable to create a new MVC application just after the installation of VS 2013, and I went through so many answers regarding it and couldn't solve the problem. At last I went to Extensions and Updates option under Tools and noticed that there were two nuget packages installed
1) Nuget Package Manager
2) Nuget Package manager for Visual studio with a blue icon

I uninstalled the second one and then the problem was solved.

Just now I noticed the problem with win32 console application.

Please help..

Comment: Your machine is pretty messed-up, tends to happen when you had VS installed before and didn't uninstall it properly.  I usually recommend running Setup.exe again with the /uninstall /force options.  Must be the right way because I never hear anything back.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will try reinstalling as you recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Passant
I started the vs_community.exe from command prompt with /Uninstall/force option.
After completing it I again started vs_community.exe with /Repair option.
That did the trick.
Now everything working perfectly for me.